# getting HttpRequestValidationException error on .NET application with "<?php echo "Content"..."

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, validation

We have a .NET 4.0 application deployed on a customer's server and while the URL for this site is technically open publicically, it is not referenced by any other site (that we know of), including search engines. However, every now and again (sometimes twice or three times in a day, sometimes once in a week), we get an exception thrown and reported;

```
2013-07-21 13:33:40.4226: Error>An uncaught exception occurred on the site (System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (="<?php echo "Content-...").
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Form()
   at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.IsAsyncPostBackRequest(HttpRequestBase request)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.HttpResponse_Redirecting(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously))
```

I am aware that `HttpRequestValidationException` is thrown when someone fills in invalid characters into a text field, eg; `<script type="javascript">GiveMeAllYourStuff()</script>` but I'm not familiar enough with PHP inparticular to guess the purpose of the content being posted. Is this an innocent case of a web spider finding the URL for the site or a bug or something more sinister?

Comment: `="<?php echo "Content-..."` looks like the script that tries to send you data is trying to see whether you execute form input as PHP. I wouldn't worry about this, given you properly escape input and aren't running PHP.

Comment: The PHP script could be any number of things; a full dump of the presumed attacker's payload would yield more information about the type and purpose of the attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably never know for sure, but it's probably good that you're leaving your guard up.

`<?php  ?>` is the opening script tag to a PHP script, just like `<%   %>` is to ASP. If I had to guess a bot is posting to every IP address it can find, and seeing if it's able to get a PHP file stored on a server so it can be used for malicious activity later.

Comment: Do you think it's worth adding code to log the full content that's triggering the validation? (I'm assuming it's possible...)

Comment: @DiskJunky If you aren't expecting this input, I'd go the complete opposite direction. Figure out how to filter this out of your logs so you don't have the noise. Then you only see the errors that matter to keeping your application running.

Comment: @DiskJunky: You might add the additional logging information in order to learn more about the attempt.  Take it as an opportunity to further strengthen your logging data.  Once you have that information though, I agree that you'd want to find a way to filter the noise.  Still log the attempts perhaps, but with a lower priority or in some other way not bring them to immediate attention.  Depends on how discerning your log "buckets" are.

Comment: @David the logging mechanism is NLog which is more than flexible enough to temporarily extract and later filter out the relevant details. Thank you!